# How do we query on a secondary index of dynamodb using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Is there a way at all to query on the `global secondary index` of dynamodb using `boto3`. I dont find any online tutorials or resources.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need to provide an `IndexName` parameter for the `query` function.

This is the ***name* of the index**, which is usually different from the **name of the index *attribute*** (the name of the index has an `-index` suffix by default, although you can change it during table creation). For example, if your index attribute is called `video_id`, your index name is probably `video_id-index`.

```py
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('videos')
video_id = 25
response = table.query(
    IndexName='video_id-index',
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('video_id').eq(video_id)
)
```

To check the **index name**, go to the `Indexes` tab of the table on the web interface of AWS. You'll need a value from the `Name` column.

Comment: if using boto3 client, see answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122093/1085343 i couldnt get key().eq() to work for some reason

Comment: Work like a charm, also it's a succinct way of doing things.

Comment: Worked for me.   Remember the GSI should have the desired partition key (ex 'video_id')

Comment: "Query condition missed key schema element: SK" -- Any ideas? Made a GSI called SK-index and set the partition key to SK. Querying using `Key("PK").eq(my_sk)`. If using `Key("SK").eq(my_sk)` instead, it returns 0 items, even though items with `SK`s definitely exist in the table.

Answer (score 12):

For anyone using the boto3 client, below example should work:

```python
import boto3    

# for production
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

# for local development if running local dynamodb server
client = boto3.client(
   'dynamodb',
   region_name='localhost',
   endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000'
)

resp = client.query(
   TableName='UsersTabe',
   IndexName='MySecondaryIndexName',
   ExpressionAttributeValues={
       ':v1': {
           'S': 'some@email.com',
       },
   },
   KeyConditionExpression='emailField = :v1',
)

# will always return list
items = resp.get('Items')

first_item = items[0]
```

Comment: To get `Key()` working you need to use the higher level `boto3.resource` and then the `Table` object, not the `boto3.client`. You also need to import `Key` (and `Attr` if needed) from `boto3.dynamodb.conditions` . There's some hard to find docs on this here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#dynamodb-conditions The nice thing about Key is that it will generate the `KeyConditionExpression` for you without having to also define `ExpressionAttributeValues` and `ExpressionAttributeNames`

Answer (score 7):

Adding the updated technique:

```py
    import boto3
    from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

    dynamodb = boto3.resource(
         'dynamodb',
         region_name='localhost',
         endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000'
    )

    table = dynamodb.Table('userTable')

    attributes = table.query(
        IndexName='UserName',
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('username').eq('jdoe')
    )
    if 'Items' in attributes and len(attributes['Items']) == 1:
        attributes = attributes['Items'][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many questions like this because calling dynamo through boto3 is not *intuitive*. I use `dynamof` library to make things like this a lot more common sense. Using `dynamof` the call looks like this.

```py
from dynamof.operations import query
from dynamof.conditions import attr

query(
    table_name='users',
    conditions=attr('role').equals('admin'),
    index_name='role_lookup_index')
```

https://github.com/rayepps/dynamof

*disclaimer: I wrote dynamof*

Answer (score 0):

like above mentioned, to use gsi query DynamoDB table, you will need to provide the index attribute. you can either input index attribute as a parameter, or you can search for corresponding index attribute via client.describe_table(). in this way, you will only need to provide table name & gsi:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

ddb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='region_like_us_east_1')
index_attribute = None    
query_result = []

# assure you had checked table do exist, then to get gsi corresponding index attribute
table_attributes = ddb.meta.client.describe_table(TableName='your table name')
if 'GlobalSecondaryIndexes' in table_attributes['Table'] and len(table_attributes['Table']['GlobalSecondaryIndexes']) > 0:
    for each_index in table_attributes['Table']['GlobalSecondaryIndexes']:
        if each_index['IndexName'] == 'your gsi':
            index_attribute = each_index['KeySchema'][0]['AttributeName']

if index_attribute:
    try:
        response = ddb.table.query(IndexName='your gsi', KeyConditionExpression=Key(index_attribute).eq('your query value'))
        query_result = response['Items']
    except ClientError as err:
        exception_value = f"Can't query {table_name} by index: {gsi} =={gsi_value}, {err.response['Error']['Code']}: {err.response['Error']['Message']}"
        print(exception_value)
        raise ValueError(exception_value)
    finally:
        return query_result
else:
    warn_value = f"Can't find the index named as {'your gsi'}"
    print(warn_value)
    return query_result
```