# How to query on GSI and partition Key with boto3 dynamo DB?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I have to query a dynamoDB table with boto3 by using the GSI and the PK, my GSI is a date and I need to get the latest date, but i don't know how to query on GSI and on the PK...

My code

```
if pk_id:
    self.__logger.info(f"DynamoDB : get current object attached to pk {pk_id}")
    item_found = self.table_query(???)
    if item_found is not None and item_found.get('Items'):
        return item_found
    else:
        return {}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we query on a secondary index of dynamodb using boto3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35758924/how-do-we-query-on-a-secondary-index-of-dynamodb-using-boto3)

Comment: It's a part from the answer, but how to query on the PK and the GSI with only one request ?

Comment: You don't......

Comment: We can't ? I don't understand ?

Comment: I believe you need to understand the concepts in DynamoDB more. A GSI has a partition key, it will allow you to read data based on a different view from your main table.

Comment: Please share the structure of your data and the query which you are trying to fulfill.

Comment: Yes it's true, it's my first day on dynamo db it's pretty hard to get all the concept :(

Comment: I suggest that you at least read the DynamoDB documentation before trying to use it.

Comment: You should be posting question on SO on your first day with a new tech, you should not be posting question in the first week or even the first month. Any question you can have in that time is answerable by doing research on your own.

Answer (score 0):

To Query a GSI it looks something like this:

```
    response = client.query(
        TableName='table-name',
        IndexName='index-name',
        ExpressionAttributeNames={
            '#pk': 'gsi_pk',
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':pk': pk_id,
        },
        KeyConditionExpression='#pk = :pk'
    )
```